# How to adjust the resizing of a SVG?

Tags: svg, responsive-design

I need some help to figure out how I can adjust the resizing of an SVG graphic when displayed on my web page.

Here are joined 2 screenshots of the graphics, [one shows the graphics on a desktop wide screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijlsA.png), and the [other on a smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29ihI.png)

My problem is the graphics are too small on the smartphone. How can I make it bigger? I didn't anything about the responsiveness of this graphics, just the plain SVG in my web page. So I guess something can be made but I don't know what exactly.

Here is the beginning of the SVG graphics:

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 1920 632" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <title>graphics</title>
    <g style="isolation:isolate">
        <g data-name="before animation starts" id="0482fa28-2c72-43bc-8627-b57f09f318d3">

<path id="main-oval" class="main-oval" d="M1354.63,260.62C1338.38,142.2,1144.68,71,922,101.54c-109.4,15-205.35,51.8-272.82,99.38-69.92,49.26-109.23,110-101,170.29,16.31,118.42,210,189.59,432.62,159.07,110.79-15.17,207.86-52.73,275.44-101.15C1324.59,380.18,1362.8,320.12,1354.63,260.62Z" data-name="oval"></path>...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Attribute names in SVG are case-sensitive. So `viewbox` should be `viewBox`.

It is possible that there are other things wring, but I can't tell without seeing the complete SVG file.

Answer (score 0):

Because your SVG has a `viewBox` attribute without a `width` and `height` attribute it is by default responsive and will scale to fit it's parent container.

In the case of your mobile view, it is the parent container that is restricting the size rather than anything in your SVG. Try inspecting the width, margin and padding of the parent container to ensure it is 100% wide and your SVG will scale to suit.

If the SVG is still not quite legible after that you will need to modify the graphic using CSS media queries to scale and transform specific elements. That is beyond the scope of the question so I won't go into it here.